# Angular Js Need multi slide carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hey folks we need a carousel in our project so I was searching for the angular-carousel and came across this link http://www.bootply.com/94452. This is exactly which is what we need but it is written in jQuery. We will not be using jQuery in our project so we need to convert this to angular. Can anyone help me how to convert this to angular. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use jQuery? Angular already uses a lightweight version of jQuery in it's core, which get's overwritten if jQuery is present. You could just create a simple wrapper for the carousel using a directive.

Comment: Thanks FrankerZ for the comment but our client is not comfortable in including external js files in the project so have to rewrite this in angular js. Can you show me how to write this angular using a directive?

Comment: @AmruthRao do you Use bootstrap in your project? If yes it can be done easily

Comment: Yes we do use bootstrap in our project

Comment: What do you mean including external js files? You're already including angular in your project, what's the difference here?

Comment: They want the whole code to be written in angular rather than writting in jQuery that's the whole point.

Comment: yes @FrankerZ even I have the same thinking why to waste time in creating something that is already there

Comment: Heh. Whether you like to admit it or not, using jQuery in a directive is the best way to go here, and it's recommended numerous times from multiple developers including the core angular team. Use directives, it's what they're used for.

Comment: @AmruthRao you can use https://github.com/jonahbron/angular-owl-carousel

Comment: Thanks for your opinions guys, so if I go for jQuery how to convert this code to angular here, can any one of help me here @frankerz and harsh

Comment: @AmruthRao no need for that https://github.com/jonahbron/angular-owl-carousel is the angular wrapper for owl-carousel you can use it directly

Comment: @harsh one quick question can we have continuous loop for this one? after reaching to the end of the carousel we want the first image coming up? any chance of that?

Comment: @AmruthRao yes it has lot of options try this http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/autoplay.html

Comment: thanks man for helping out.@harsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://github.com/jonahbron/angular-owl-carousel

which is an angular wrapper for http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/